Pyroscope agent failing to load after changing version
I encountered the following issue:
I was trying to dockerize some monitoring applications and this happened:
This first version of the dockerfile works fine:

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates -y && update-ca-certificates

ENV PYROSCOPE_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://pyroscope:4040
ENV PYROSCOPE_APPLICATION_NAME=pet-clinic-app
ENV PYROSCOPE_FORMAT=jfr
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILING_INTERVAL=10ms
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_EVENT=itimer
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_LOCK=10ms
ENV PYROSCOPE_PROFILER_ALLOC=512k
ENV PYROSCOPE_UPLOAD_INTERVAL=15s
ENV PYROSCOPE_LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV PYROSCOPE_LABELS="hostname=pet-clinic-app"

ENV OTEL_JAVAAGENT_EXTENSIONS=./pyroscope-otel.jar

ENV OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=pet-clinic-app
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://tempo:4318
ENV OTEL_PYROSCOPE_ADD_PROFILE_URL=true
ENV OTEL_PYROSCOPE_ADD_PROFILE_BASELINE_URL=true
ENV OTEL_PYROSCOPE_START_PROFILING=true
ENV OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=none
ENV OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=none
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
ENV OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES="container=monitoring-application-1"


COPY target/spring-petclinic-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
COPY src/main/resources/application.properties /application.properties
WORKDIR /opt/app

ADD https://github.com/grafana/pyroscope-java/releases/download/v0.12.2/pyroscope.jar /opt/app/pyroscope.jar
ADD https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/pyroscope/otel/0.10.1.11/otel-0.10.1.11.jar pyroscope-otel.jar


CMD ["java", "-javaagent:./opentelemetry-javaagent.jar", "-javaagent:pyroscope.jar", "-Dspring.config.location=/application.properties", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]



After changing VERSION : ADD https://github.com/grafana/pyroscope-java/releases/download/v0.12.2/pyroscope.jar /opt/app/pyroscope.jar  to v0.14.0 
I started getting the following error in my application container:
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
2024-10-07 18:42:47 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /tmp/root-pyroscope/libasyncProfiler-linux-x64-98e96b2eb57e823a37267f19311d25e9d476f3.so already loaded in another classloader
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:201)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2389)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at io.pyroscope.one.profiler.AsyncProfiler.getInstance(AsyncProfiler.java:36)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at io.pyroscope.labels.io.pyroscope.PyroscopeAsyncProfiler.getAsyncProfiler(PyroscopeAsyncProfiler.java:32)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at io.pyroscope.javaagent.Profiler.<init>(Profiler.java:27)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at io.pyroscope.javaagent.PyroscopeAgent$Options$Builder.<init>(PyroscopeAgent.java:114)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at io.pyroscope.javaagent.PyroscopeAgent.start(PyroscopeAgent.java:33)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     at io.pyroscope.javaagent.PyroscopeAgent.premain(PyroscopeAgent.java:25)
2024-10-07 18:42:47     ... 6 more
2024-10-07 18:42:47 *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
2024-10-07 18:42:47 FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
2024-10-07 18:42:47 #
2024-10-07 18:42:47 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
2024-10-07 18:42:47 #
2024-10-07 18:42:47 #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f461fcf4602, pid=1, tid=7
2024-10-07 18:42:47 #
2024-10-07 18:42:47 # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (17.0.2+8) (build 17.0.2+8-86)
2024-10-07 18:42:47 # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
2024-10-07 18:42:47 # Problematic frame:
2024-10-07 18:42:47 # C  [libc.so.6+0x25602]  abort+0x1ee

Sadly my knowledge to java agents is very limited and I got introduced to the concept very recently, therefore this is very hard for me to debug. Anyone has an idea why this version upgrade suddenly breaks everything. This is the only change made in the Dockerfile.
Application used : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic
Docker-compose configs : https://file.io/I7FHj7rLQzSj
Its a bit messed up but it was a long trial and error process :)
Thanks for the help in advance. Hopefully I provided enough information.
